# Привязка данных в Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Как привязать данные с двух input (name и  password) к объекту user, чтоб они были его свойствами. Работаю в Angularjs.

Answer (score 4):

Так:

```
$scope.user = {};

<input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
<input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
```